# JVM Launched via CreateProcess() Loses Classpath Library

Tags: java, windows, process, jvm, classpath

I launch the following command line (process) from a Windows VC++ 6 program using CreateProcess (or _spawnv()):

- java -cp c:\dir\updates.jar;c:\dir\main.jar Main

and class updates in updates.jar (overiding some in main.jar) are not read or found.  It is as if the updates.jar library cannot be found or read.

If I launch the same line from a shortcut, or from the command line proper, everything IS found and executes properly.

If I launch a JVM from the command line, keep it running, AND THEN launch the executable stub (above), then everything works OK also.  (This makes it look like the issue is a file rights thing).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

--Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Microsoft's FileMon utility to figure out what's happening.  Set the include filter to "updates" to focus in on the problem.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on another machine? Another OS? Which JVM are you using? Have you tried different JVMs?

Can you provide us with a minimal example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **jdigital**!

I tried FileMon and it showed me what I was doing wrong.  The executable calling CreateProcess() had an unclosed file handle to updates.jar from an attempt to copy the update JAR earlier.  Bad code that works in the production environment, but not in the test environment.